# Write a program that demonstrate the technique of overloading copy constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I had try to combine constructor overloading and copy constructor to achive the solution of the above question

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Area{
    public:
        float ar;
        Area(int l){
            ar=l*l;
        }
        Area(double r){
                ar=3.14*r*r;
          }
          void display(){
            cout<<ar<<endl;
          }
};
int main(){
    Area obj1(1);
    obj1.display();
    Area obj2(1.2);
    obj2.display();
    obj1=obj2;//here obj1=1.2 and it call the constructor area(double)
    obj1.display();//

}
```

so i had finalize theabove code and there is zero error on compilation. It is right or wrong??

Comment: There is no overloaded copy constructors.

Comment: Overloading copy constructor seems strange `C(const C&)` vs `C(C&)` (plus `volatile` versions).

Answer (score 0):

This program is compiled by g++ without any problems. Which compiler do you use? This code demonstrates a copy constructor and an assignment operator

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Area{
    private:
        float ar;
    public:
        Area(int l){
            cout<< "Area(int l)" <<endl;
            ar=l*l;
        }
        Area(double r){
            cout<< "Area(double r)" <<endl;
            ar=3.14*r*r;
        }
        void display(){
            cout<<ar<<endl;
        }
        Area(const Area& other) {
            cout<< "copy constructor" <<endl;
            ar = other.ar;
        }
        Area& operator=(const Area& other) {
            cout<< "assignment operator" <<endl;
            ar = other.ar;
            return *this;
        }
};
int main(){
    Area obj1(1); // Area(int l) is called
    obj1.display();

    Area obj2(1.2); // Area(double r) is called
    obj2.display();

    Area obj3(obj1); // Area(const Area& other) is called
    obj3.display();

    obj1=obj2; // operator=() is called
    obj1.display();
    return 0; // Return a code to operating system according to program state
}
```